# Пользовательский класс наследующий список

Tags: python, ооп

Допустим имется код Python:

```
>>>class Mylist(list): pass
>>>y = Mylist('ab')
>>>y
['a','b' ]
>>>y.__dict__
{}
```

Создал экземпляр  класса Mylist. Но почему при выводе экземпляра выводится список? я ведь создал не экземпляр списка, а экземпляр класса Mylist. т.е в выражение Mylist( ) 
транслируется в 'list.**new**(Mylist)', в первом аргументе передан класс Mylist, экземпляр которого и был создан. Да и экземпляры пользовательских классов  хранят информацию о состоянии в атрибутах, словарь которых пуст

Comment: Преодолевать трудности -- это круто. Только вот неужели так прикольно их создавать?

Comment: Вы бы про ООП сначала почитали, потом вопросы бы позадавали и только потом уже стали бы список переопределять...

Матчасть учите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так-с... давайте по-порядку.

```
1. class A(list):
2.    pass
3. a = A('123');
4. print a
```

Что мы здесь делаем?
1) объявляем класс A, который наследуется от класса list
2) этот класс мы не переопределяем, т.е. внешне он ведет себя так же, как и list, но при этом это будет именно наш класс, т.к.

```
print type(a)
```

отобразит <class '**main**.A'>. При этом если мы сделаем

```
print isinstance(a, list)
```

то увидим TRUE, т.к. 'a' - это объект класса, порожденного от list.

3) создаем объект А, но поскольку мы не переопределили конструктор list, то он и будет вызван - он установит внутреннее состояние "экземпляра в котором создаются данные".
4) поскольку приведение к строке мы не переопределяли, то будет вызвано приведение к строке класса list. Он и отображает данные нашего класса в том виде, в котором отображает их просто list.

Зачем нужны такие объявления? Например, для исключений. Мы создали несколько (различных) собственных исключений и кидаем их. Где-то в стеке выше мы эти исключения ловим и по типу определяем какие действия необходимо выполнить. Т.е. с одной стороны это исключения, с другой стороны - это НАШИ исключения, которые мы можем смело использовать, т.к. никто кроме нас их не использует.

Идем дальше - переопределим конструктор:

```
1. class B(list):
2.    mylist = None;
3.    def __init__(self, mylist = None):
4.        self.mylist = mylist
5. b = B('123');
6. print b
```

1) то же что и выше. Не стал наследоваться от A, чтобы вы увидели что разница между классами A и B - только в конструкторе.
2) добавили свой параметр, который отсутствует в родительском классе list
3-4) мы переопределили родительский конструктор так, чтобы учитывать свои параметры.
5) так же создаем наш класс, но здесь уже не будет вызван конструктор класса list, т.к. мы его явно переопределили
6) Мы переопределили конструктор, теперь конструктор списка не вызывается, а значит при попытке напечатать список мы увидим, что он пуст. Но он же не пуст! Т.е. мы же в объекте сохранили некоторое значение! Почему его не видно?

А потому что мы унаследовались от list, а значит печать на экран происходит по правилам list. Но так как мы переопределили конструктор и ничего в список не положили, то на экран будет выведен пустой список.

Значит нам необходимо переписать наш класс так, чтобы мы могли отразить его текущее состояние в том виде, в котором это надо нам:

```
1. class C(list):
2.    mylist = None;
3.    def __init__(self, mylist = None):
4.        self.mylist = mylist
5.    def __repr__(self):
6.        return self.mylist
7. c = C('123')
8. print c
```

1-4) то же, что и выше
5-6) мы переопределили метод, который приводил наш объект в строку. (честно скажу - переопределили очень плохо, но сейчас мы не об этом)
7) создаем наш объект, здесь вызывается только наш конструктор, а не конструктор list
8) выводим на экран наш объект, для этого выполняется его приведение к строке. Поскольку мы переопределили метод приведения к строке, то будет отображен уже наш новый объект, а не то, что раньше.

И еще один пример:

```
-. class D(list):
-.    mylist = None;
1.    ownShow = False
-.    def __init__(self, mylist = None):
-.        self.mylist = mylist
-.    def __repr__(self):
2.        self.ownShow = not self.ownShow
3.        if self.ownShow:
4.            return self.mylist
5.        else:
6.            return super(D, self).__repr__()
7. d = D('123')
8. print d
9. print d
10. print d
11. print d
```

Здесь мы создаем класс D, который делаем то же, что и C, но несколько по другому.
Строчки, отмеченные как '-.' - взяты из класса C.
1) добавили параметр, по которому будем определять какой способ приведения к строке будем использовать
2) при каждом приведении к строке будем переключать наш параметр так, чтобы сначала мы получили один результат, затем другой, потом опять первый результат.
3) здесь проверяем использовать наш приведение к строке или не стандартное для list
4) так мы приводим к строке
5) если использовать стандартное приведение list, то
6) вызываем явно стандартное поведение для родительского класса. Не явно вызвать не получится, т.к. мы уже переопределили данный метод в своем классе.
7) создаем наш объект
8, 10) выведет наше приведение к строке
9, 11) выведет стандартное приведение к строке

---

Попытался все разжевать, но я не учитель, поэтому хорошо объяснять не должен. Если вы и в таком виде не поймете где ваша ошибка, то настоятельно рекомендую вам не лезть в дебри сейчас. У вас слабая матчасть, вы судя по всему вообще не понимаете как работают классы, вот матчасть и качайте.

Comment: Вы согласны с этим? Опять в метод наследуемый моим классом из класса list,  в первом аргументе получает мой класс, а не класс List. Ну и где же здесь создается экземпляр класса list? Покажите место в программе где вы видите что в моем экземпляре создается список для вывода. Ведь методы сами по себе ничего не выводят, они обрабатывают экземпляры значения которых выводят, а пространство имен моего экземпляра к тому же пусто. Может быть просто выполняется какая-то неявная связь между моим объектом и списком?

Comment: @Maksim, init - это конструктор. В нем вы задаете начальное состояние объекта. Переопределив конструктор, вы измените дефолтное поведение базового класса. В своем втором примере я его переопределил, поэтому при выводе на экран получаем пустой список.

Про new вы сказали правильно, но ведь вы этот метод не переопределяли! Посмотрите следующий пример:

    class A(list):
        def __new__(cls,*dt,**mp):
            return 1
    a = A('123')
    print a
    print type(a)
    print isinstance(a, list)

Здесь я переопределил только создание объекта - на выходе получаю объект другого типа.

Comment: @Maksim, вот только зачем переопределять класс, если вы не хотите при этом создавать объекты данного типа?

Попробую описать подробнее:

    a = MyList('123')
    print a

Что делает компилятор:

1. ищет в MyList метод new. Его нет, поэтому ищет этот метод в классе list, от которого мы наследуемся (и находит его).
2. вызывает метод new класс list - возвращается объект list (!)
3. ищет в MyList конструктор. Его нет, поэтому ищет этот метод в классе list, от которого мы наследуемся (и находит его).
4. вызывается конструктор класса list, ему передает параметры, переданные нашему классу

Comment: 4. (продолжение) этими параметрами инициализируется внутреннее состояние объекта нашего класса
5. ищем в MyList метод, преобразующий наш класс в строку. Его нет, поэтому ищет этот метод в классе list, от которого мы наследуемся (и находим его).
6. выводим на экран полученное строковое значение.

Вот и все. Поскольку вы не переопределили ни один из родительских классов, то вызываются именно они, хотя вы ручками вроде ничего сами не вызываете - все происходит автоматически, иначе зачем нужно наследование?

Что сейчас не понятно?

Comment: Мне все понятно, но только 2й пункт оставляет вопросы. 
'вызывает метод new класс list - возвращается объект list (!)' 
Почему метод new должен возвращать объект list? Этот метод возвращает тот объект класс которого передан в первом аргументе, т.е Mylist. и что за метод 'преобразующий наш класс в строку'? нет такого метода. Есть метод repr который выводит строковое представление экземпляра. Который тоже в первом аргументе получает экземпляр класса list.

Comment: И еще, заметил интересную особенность, что почему-то именно метод __new__ встроенного типа не создает экземпляр если передаваемый ему класс не является подклассом встроенного типа

Comment: @Maksim, вам надо срочно бросать программирование, либо искать того, кто сможет каким-либо образом хоть немного объяснить что же действительно происходит...

MyList - это и есть list, вы это понимаете? Это не int, не str, это list, т.к. мы наследуемся от него

В комментах я привел пример, когда создается объект int, но это потому что мы создаем сами объект другого типа, даже не класса A.

Сами посмотрите что выведет print isinstance(a, A).

Это потому что мы сами вернули другой объект, а не экземпляр нашего класса MyList (который на самом деле расширенный list).

Comment: А про "преобразующий наш класс в строку" - это уже просто придирки...

Answer (score 0):

у тебя инит наследуется от списка, потому и создается список

Comment: А причем тут __init__, init не создает объекты. init я могу переопределить в подклассе и все равно при выводе моего объекта выведется список

Comment: >и все равно при выводе моего объекта выведется список
перечитал весь пост, заметил там еще один вопрос:
>Но почему при выводе экземпляра выводится список?

потому что репр тоже наследуется от списка

Comment: repr то наследуется, но он заполняет в первом аргументе экземпляр моего класса

Comment: я не понимаю, что ты имеешь ввиду

Answer (score 0):

Не понял в чем проблема.

```
>>> y.__class__
<class '__main__.Mylist'>
```

А то, что он ведет себя как список, так это логично, он же от него унаследован. Хотите изменить это поведение? Не проблема - переопределяйте нужные методы.

```
>>> class Mylist(list):
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return '\n'.join(('Item: %r' % x for x in self))
... 
>>> y = Mylist('abcde')
>>> y
Item: 'a'
Item: 'b'
Item: 'c'
Item: 'd'
Item: 'e'
```

Comment: Выражение Mylist(), наследует метод перегруженный метод new из списка, который в первом аргументе получает мой класс Mylist, поэтому и создается экземпляр моего класса. Но почему выводится список ведь мы его даже не создали

Comment: Да и экземпляры пользовательских классов хранят информацию о состоянии в атрибутах. И где в моем экземпляре создается список?

Comment: Потому что за вывод в консоль [строкового представления объекта](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) отвечает метод `__repr__`, который был так же был унаследован от списка.

Comment: хм...

    y = Mylist('ab')

а разве этим вы не список создаете?

Т.е. грубо есть класс "Животное". Вы от него унаследовали класс "Кошка", потом создаете объект этого класса и жалуетесь, что у вас в итоге животное получается...

Comment: Сорри, забыл уточнить - это тов. @Maksim было сказано

Comment: Что значит "не создали"? Конструкция `y = MyList('ab')` транслируется не просто в `list.__new__(MyList)`, а ещё и в `list.__init__('ab')` (потому как в классе `MyList` не определён метод `__init__`, и интерпретатор ищет его в классах-предках, в данном случае в `list`). Хотите неинициализированный объект класса `MyList` - вызывайте `MyList.__new__(MyList)`.

Comment: Насчёт аттрибутов: `y.__dict__` выводит собственные атрибуты объекта класса `MyList`, которых у него нет. А вот `dir(y)` выведет все унаследованные от `list` атрибуты, среди которых есть и `__repr__` из класса `list`, который и выводит данные, которыми вы его инициализировали.

Comment: @Maksim, см. мой комментарий про матчасть, вы вообще не понимаете как это все работает.

Ваш класс - и есть list, если не поняли - вы от него унаследовались, а значит им и являетесь

Comment: Ещё раз, если какой-то метод не найден в текущем классе, он ищется в классе-предке. А предком вашего класса является класс `list`, в котором и сохраняются те данные, которые вы передали в инициализатор.

Comment: Данные не сохраняются в классах, классы обрабатывают экземпляры в которых создают данные. А наследую я только два метода new и init, который заполняют в первом аргументе мой класс и экземпляр этого класса соответственно. Ну и где же вы тут видете что создается объект списка? Я еще раз повторяю все унаследованные методы работают только с моими экземплярами

Comment: @Maksim, вы вообще не понимаете как и что здесь происходит.

Учите матчасть.

    y = Mylist('ab')

этим вы вызываете конструктор своего класса (т.е. создаете объект), но поскольку вы явно конструктор своего класса не описали, то используется конструктор родительского класса, а он как раз и создает список.

Вот только у вас на выходе будет не обычный список, а список, вами дополненный (или расширенный, если вам так удобнее) Т.е. на выходе будет объект класса Mylist, который по существу является списком, т.к. вы от него унаследовались

Comment: Подождите. Начнем стого что init не создает объекты, объекты создает new. Я могу даже переопределить init в своем подклассе, но все равно при выводе моего класса будет почему-то выводится список. Так что давайте оставим этот метод в стороне. Вообще наследование от list означает что мой класс всего лишь будет использовать те методы которые имеются в классе list и обрабатывать ими СВОИ экземпляры. Выражение Mylist() транслируется в list.new(Mylist)

Comment: Опять в метод наследуемый моим классом из класса list, в первом аргументе получает мой класс, а не класс List. Ну и где же здесь создается экземпляр класса list? Покажите место в программе где вы видите что в моем экземпляре создается список для вывода. Ведь методы сами по себе ничего не выводят, они обрабатывают экземпляры значения которых выводят, а пространство имен моего экземпляра к тому же пусто. Может быть просто выполняется какая-то неявная связь между моим объектом и списком?